# Entity Framework - connection properties from user

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I'm creating application, that will be able to connect to any database which user wishes. I'm trying to connect, but I'm always getting exception about connection string. My code looks like:

```
public string GetConnectionString(string userName, string password, string database, string server)
{
    return string.Format(
                @"metadata=res://*/Data.Database.csdl|res://*/Data.Database.ssdl|res://*/Data.Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={0};initial catalog={1};persist security info=True;user id={2};password={3};multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;",
                server,
                database,
                userName,
                password);
    }
```

and

```
DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(GetConnectionString(UserName, Password, DatabaseName, ServerName));
```

What is wrong with my connection string? I just copied it from app.config file.

Comment: What is the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: "Keyword not supported: 'data source'."

Answer (score 0):

Answer is on this page: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738533(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They are creating SqlConnectionStringBuilder and after that EntityConnectionStringBuilder which produces proper Entity Framework connection string.